# Why does ng2-semantic-ui multi-select show "No results"?

Tags: angular, select, semantic-ui, multi-select, ng2-semantic-ui

I have a filter function for my table. Previously I was using `suiDropdown` and it is working fine.

I want to change it to multi-select so I used `sui-multi-select`. 
But why does it show "No results"?

**suiDropdown:**

```
<div class="ui dropdown" suiDropdown>
        <div class="text">雇用区分</div>
        <a><i class="dropdown icon"></i></a>
        <div class="menu" suiDropdownMenu>
            <div class="item" name="clear" (click)="onSelectFilter('category', '')">クリア</div>
            <div class="item" *ngFor="let cat of categories" (click)="onSelectFilter('category', cat)">{{cat}}</div>
        </div>
</div>
```

**sui-multi-select:**

```
<sui-multi-select class="selection"
                    [(ngModel)]="empCategory"
                    [options]="categories"
                    [hasLabels]="false"
                    [placeholder]="'クリア'"
                    (focusout)="onSelectFilter('category')"
                    #multiCateg>
        <sui-select-option *ngFor="let cat of multiCateg.filteredOptions"
                            [value]="cat">
        </sui-select-option>
</sui-multi-select>
```

Bottomline: *suiDropdown* displays the `categories` but *sui-multi-select* just shows "No results"